# Missing resource Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception, jboss

I'm getting following exception in production. Unable to reproduce the same in local instance. This exception disappears once server is restarted. Unable to figure out root cause for this exception. All properties files are present in the build.

Exception is :

```
2014-02-01 00:00:32,363 INFO  [STDOUT] Missing resource : org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/problem/messages.properties for locale en_US
2014-02-01 00:00:32,363 INFO  [STDOUT] java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.messages, locale en_US
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:836)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:726)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:576)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.DefaultProblemFactory.loadMessageTemplates(DefaultProblemFactory.java:176)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.DefaultProblemFactory.<init>(DefaultProblemFactory.java:42)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:322)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:288)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:267)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,364 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:255)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:556)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:293)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1083)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:396)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:232)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.qfundlite.wl.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.qfundlite.wl.filters.PerfFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:153)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:81)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:481)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:307)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:385)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:748)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:678)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:871)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,365 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,366 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ql].[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Localizer.getMessage(Localizer.java:56)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:565)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:293)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1083)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:396)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:232)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at com.qfundlite.wl.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at com.qfundlite.wl.filters.PerfFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:153)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:81)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:307)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:385)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:748)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:678)
at org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:871)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
    2014-02-01 00:00:32,366 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ql].[action]] Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Localizer.getMessage(Localizer.java:56)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:565)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:293)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1083)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:396)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:232)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at com.qfundlite.wl.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at com.qfundlite.wl.filters.PerfFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:153)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:81)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:307)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:385)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:748)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:678)
at org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:871)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2014-02-01 00:00:32,366 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.session.JBossCacheManager] check to see if needs to store and replicate session with id iTCg3nsAz8fcBgDh0ipjYQ**.node1
2014-02-01 00:00:32,367 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.session.ClusteredSession] processSessionRepl(): session is dirty. Will increment version from: 9 and replicate.
```

JBoss 4.2 is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with 1.5.1?

Please refer below mentioned link & will help you:

http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=649

Thanks!!!

Comment: using JDK 1.5_06..Thanks for the reply!!